# external javascript file cause memory leak in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

I try to execute this code in IE (6 and 8), it works properly but IE causes memory leak while executing it.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file_with_data.html" id=currentJsData></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function currentJsDataRefresh()
{
document.getElementById('currentJsData').src="file_with_data.html";
}


setInterval(currentJsDataRefresh, 300);

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

An extract of other file, file_with_data.html, containing javascript data sources as global variables:

```
var xMax;
var array1 = new Array();
var array2 = new Array();
var array3 = new Array();
array1[0] = 123;
array1[0] = 456;
...
```

I tried to insert a function that deletes all vars putting them equal null but memory leak persists. Can you explain what happen in IE?

Comment: Why are you trying to load javascript file every 300ms? You'd be better off using AJAX to retrieve the contents of the HTML and deal with it that way

Comment: Is `file_with_data.html` even pure JavaScript? Why isn't it a `.js`?

Comment: I think you need to provide a more concrete example because there shouldn't be any leaks in the code you posted. It's probably some (anti)patterns in your real application that prevent some objects from being GC'ed

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Looks like you have (i)frames in your app, it would help if you provided a more complete code example.</strike> *Sorry didn't read the question carefully*

Meanwhile check for this issue: [Externally Declared Global Variable Leak](http://novemberborn.net/2006/04/javascriptedgvl-85) (check the code demos)

This may happen when you declare global variables inside one frame while being in the context of another frame.

Comment: I have no (i)frame in my app. Code is complete, i didn't include all vars in file_with_data.html: they are a dozen of array with each has a twelve of elements. Many thanks.

Comment: How do you use this data? do you reference it somewhere?

Comment: Can you try to create one single object in `file_with_data` that would encapsulate all the data, instead of creating multiple vars? E.g. `var data = {xMax: 123, array1: [123, 346], array2: ...}`

Comment: it's a good idea but that file is the result of a former processing, in other words, it is an input. Furthermore i wrote a function put null all variables, if i encapsulate all data in a object and than i put it to null before i refresh the external file, is not it the same thing? Many thanks!

Comment: Encapsulating all data in an object might give you more control over possible leaks (you care about one global variable, not many). Since we're talking about some IE-specific quirks, I'd give it a try just for the sake of experiment...